# Elasticsearch 2.2 query to test a number of query strings against the same field

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I was wondering if somone had tried or recommends the best way to match a single field with multiple query strings. Easiest way to explain this is to say that I want to do the equivalent of `WHERE name = "jeff" OR name = "thomas" OR name = "harry"` in mysql, but translate it to elasticsearch match query.

I would like the results to take each query condition on its own ignoring what the other queries return.

effectively It is this query

```
{
    "query": {
                { "match": { "title": "Brown fox" }}
    }
}
```

But with the ability to add additional match queries. I could run multiple queries but I think it would be more efficient (and would prefer) to run it as one query.

I have tried:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                { "match": { "title": "Brown fox" }},
                { "match": { "body":  "Brown fox" }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But the scoring is affected based on matches across all queries. Ideally i want the score to be based on the single query only.

the dis_max query

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_best_fields.html#dis-max-query

Seems to be the closest to what I'am after but the scoring still appears to be affected by the other queries.The scores from a dis_match seem to be completely different to the `query:{match:{}}` scores.

At the end of the day I'm wanting to write a query that tries to match a query string but also try a number of variations and abbreviation replacements of the string e.g `where name="company ltd" OR name="company limited"` where the other condition is irrelevant.

**Question Summary**

Has anyone come across a better query method for running queries with multiple conditions where each condition is independent of another and returns results and scores accordingly?

If nothing else comes up I will probably use the dis_match query type.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the only way I could guarantee independent searches within the same request was to use the multi-search API endpoint and stick the responses together into one results array

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search